# how to quick input current date & time with a quick word?

Tags: scripts, fcitx

There is an addon in `fcitx` where you can associate a word with some other string like "smile （・∀・）" entered in at `~/.config/fcitx/data/QuickPhrase.mb`. When you type `smile` it outputs （・∀・）`

I want the same thing but a function rather than a word; I want it to output a current timestamp.

For example:  when I input "time", it outputs the current time "2016-08-03 11:15",one minute later ,when I input "time", it outputs "2016-08-03 11:16"

Comment: What is meant by _when I want to input "time"_? you want a keyboard shortcut do the job or like a snippet

Comment: Thinks ! @Zanna

Comment: Don't  know much about  that add on,  but I could  make a script that copies whatever string you want to clipboard,  which can be used with current  date.  Does that sound OK?

Comment: does it work under fcitx? @Serg

Comment: @dindom it works regardless of the input method, so `fcitx` or `xim` or any other - doesn't matter. It still going to work, because it uses clipboard

Comment: @dindom actually, can you give me the name of that plugin ? I'll make both answers - workaround and the one for plugin ( if i figure out that plugin, of course )

Comment: Aha,found it. That's `quickphrase` plugin. It will be quite easy, I think.  Just a question. How do I trigger the keyword ? like `smile` ?

Comment: OK, I've posted an answer. Please review it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In this post**:

1. Introduction
2. `QuickPhrase_Time.py` script
3. `xclip` shortcut

## 1.Introduction

The plugin to which OP refers to, is [QuickPhrase](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/QuickPhrase) and can be installed via `sudo apt-get install fcitx-modules fcitx-module-quickphrase-editor`. It uses `~/.config/fcitx/data/QuickPhrase.mb` to store phrases.

The main objective here is to have easy way of inserting a string which contains current time into text filed that user is currently editing. Below there are two solutions.

---

## 2. QuickPhrase_Time.py script

This script continuously edits the line in config file which has `time_now` 
phrase , and appends current time to the line. This script is meant to be launched [automatically on login to GUI](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/295286).

Usage is simple:

```
 python /path/to/QuickPhrase_Timer.py
```

#### Script source

Also available as [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/SergKolo/c362a2dac3fca17ab520c8dd077d3400) , updated versions likely will go there.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import time
import os


def run_cmd(cmdlist):
    """ Reusable function for running external commands """
    new_env = dict( os.environ ) 
    new_env['LC_ALL'] = 'C' 
    try:
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist,env=new_env)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass
    else:
        if stdout:
            return stdout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_home = os.path.expanduser('~')
    config_file = '.config/fcitx/data/QuickPhrase.mb'
    config_full_path = os.path.join(user_home,config_file)
    found = None

    while True:
         lines = []
         time.sleep(1)
         with open(config_full_path) as f:
              for line in f:
                  lines.append(line.strip())
                  if line.startswith('time_now'):
                      found = True
         # print(lines)
         if found:
             with open(config_full_path,'w') as f:
                  for line in lines:
                      if line.startswith('time_now'):
                         time_now = run_cmd(['date', 
                                             '+%Y-%m-%d %I:%M'
                                             ]).decode().strip()
                         line = 'time_now ' + time_now + '\n'
                      else:
                         line = line + '\n'
                      f.write(line)
```

---

## 3. xclip shortcut

In case the above python script won't work for you, here's a workaround: bind the command below to a keyboard shortcut

```
xclip -sel clip <<< $( date +%Y-%m-%d\ %I:%M )
```

Essentially, what this does is copies output of `date` to your clipboard, which you can then release via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcut ( which is common for most applications as paste shortcut).

This approach doesn't rely on `fctix` or any other input method, hence is more flexible and reliable.

**Note** that `xclip` is not installed by default. Obtain it via `sudo apt-get install xclip`

Comment: Thinks @Serg !  "QuickPhrase_Timer.py" is a good point, but not a good solution,because it's keep running all the time.

Comment: @dindom it keeps running  all the time but the CPU usage is very minimal,  if that's  what you're  concerned about.

Comment: @dindom I doubt there is a method where you do not have something running all the time. It is a low footprint that matters.

Answer (score 0):

You may use lua to extend quickphrase for fcitx/fcitx5.

The lua relevant API is based on old Google Pinyin lua on Windows. You may refer to this doc to see what extra API are available: https://fcitx.github.io/fcitx5-lua/modules/ime.html (only ime module works for fcitx4, the fcitx module is only in fcitx5.)

### fcitx4

In fcitx4 lua is a built-in addon. Your distribution may split it in to a sperate package. On ubuntu it's called fcitx-module-lua.

You may create a .lua file under ~/.config/fcitx/lua .

### fcitx5

Basically the API is the same, but the path is slightly different. And now it's a separate package, fcitx5-lua. On ubuntu it's called fcitx5-module-lua.

You may put the .lua file under ~/.local/share/fcitx5/lua/imeapi/extensions instead.

Here is a script that works for both fcitx/fcitx5, taken from https://github.com/lilydjwg/fcitx-lua-scripts/blob/master/date.lua

```
function LookupDate(input)
  local fmt
  if input == '' then
    fmt = "%Y年%m月%d日"
  elseif input == 't' then
    fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  elseif input == 'd' then
    fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
  end
  return os.date(fmt)
end

ime.register_command("dt", "LookupDate", "日期时间输入")
```

Fcitx5 also comes with a built-in lua script https://github.com/fcitx/fcitx5-chinese-addons/blob/master/im/pinyin/pinyin.lua , but that checks the input method name is Pinyin or Shuangpin.

You may also take it as a reference since it contains more than just date/time and support more fancy format.